# jsRender loop a List<string>

Tags: jsrender

A question on the {{for}} loop in `jsRender`.

The demo shows we can loop through a collection of complex objects and display their properties:

```
{{for languages}}
    <div>
        <em>{{>name}}</em>
    </div>
{{/for}}
```

But what if my `languages` is only a `List<string>`? There will be no `{{>name}}` to be displayed. How can we reference the individual string values?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should be able to use `#data` to access the individual string values inside the loop.

Comment: just out of curiosity, is this a documented method?

Comment: @mattlohkamp There's a mention of it [here](https://www.jsviews.com/#paths) ("_`#data` is short for `#view.data`_") and [here](https://www.jsviews.com/#views@datacontext) ("_a view has a data property, which is the current data context used for rendering that view_")

Comment: need an example in context

Comment: This is a very old answer and while it was correct at the time it's entirely possible that it's not relevant to recent versions of jsRender.  I haven't used jsRender for several years and have not kept up with their changes.

Answer (score 20):

```
{{#data}}
```

Didn't work for me.

Something seems to have been changed, this is what did it for me:

```
{{>#data}}
```

Comment: @r2b2s - actually it's the exact opposite. "The {{> ...}} tag should be used instead of the {{: ...}} whenever data being rendered is not fully trusted – in order to protect against HTML injection attacks." - https://www.jsviews.com/#htmltag

Answer (score 7):

**You should use:**

`{{>#data}}` or `{{>}}` - (encodes HTML)

`{{:#data}}` or `{{:}}` - (non HTML)

**For example:**

Let's say your `languages` object looks like this:

`var languages = ['en', 'sp', 'zh'];`

```
{{for languages}}
    <div>
        <em>{{>}}</em>
    </div>
{{/for}}
```

**Will result in:**

```
<div>
   <em>en</em>
</div>
<div>
   <em>sp</em>
</div>
<div>
   <em>zh</em>
</div>
```

---

**Documentation**

[#data](https://www.jsviews.com/#viewobject@data)

[Difference between `:` and `>`](https://www.jsviews.com/#htmltag)

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you want to do some comparisons, you can use code like:

```
{{if #data == 'xxx' || #data == 'yyy'}}
...
{{/if}}
```

in the script.